# Can EF Core list navigation property with Guid foreign key return more than one entity using Include?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have two tables, that I cannot change. Both have a job_id column, which is a Guid that essentially connects these tables in a one to many relationship.

There are no foreign keys between these tables in SQL. I want to have two ef core entities, with a navigation property between them. One SysJob with many SysJobSteps.

Is it possible for a list navigation property with a Guid foreign key to return more than a single entity?

Here is my code:

```
public class SysJob
{
    public Guid JobId { get; set; }

    public List<SysJobStep> SysJobSteps { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class SysJobStep
{
    public Guid JobId { get; set; }

    public SysJob SysJob { get; set; }

    public string StepName { get; set; }
    public string Command { get; set; }
}
```

model builder:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SysJob>()
    .HasKey(j => j.JobId);
modelBuilder.Entity<SysJob>()
    .HasMany(j => j.SysJobSteps)
    .WithOne(s => s.SysJob)
    .HasForeignKey(j => j.JobId);

modelBuilder.Entity<SysJobStep>()
     .HasKey(s => s.JobId);
```

However my query with include only returns one SysJobStep for each SysJob:

```
var x = context.SysJobs
    .Include(j => j.SysJobSteps)
    .ToList();
```

I logged the query into Console and found out, that EF Core itself calls a sql query, that returns more rows than the linq query.

Comment: `SysJobStep` cannot have `JobId` as its Key. You should set it to `x => new { x.JobId, x.StepName, x.Command }` so the unique constraint on the primary key can be respected. You only see one detail record because they all share the same (primary) Key and EF Core will load only the first entity

Comment: This means: the shared key `JobId` turns it into a 1:1 association.

Comment: You are correct, ef core has to be set to use the "step_uid" column as a key.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the navigation property returns only a single entity is because the job_id column is not unique. The "step_uid" column should be used.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SysJobStep>()
    .HasKey(s => s.StepUId);
```

```
public class SysJobStep
{
    public Guid JobId { get; set; }
    public Guid StepUId { get; set; }

    public SysJob SysJob { get; set; }

    public string StepName { get; set; }
    public string Command { get; set; }
}
```